# Disable others inputs on click

Tags: javascript

```
      answerElement.addEventListener("click", () => { // Evénement pour mettre une couleur si c'est juste ou faux
  
    CreateLabel.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // On set le style a blanc de base
    if (value[i].propositions[j] == value[i].réponse) {

      CreateLabel.style.backgroundColor = "green"; // On set le style a green quand c'est juste
  
      console.log(answerElement)
      answerElement.disabled = true;

      const anecdoteElement = document.createElement("p");

      const anecdoteNode = document.createTextNode(value[i].anecdote); // Crée l'anecdote quand c'est juste


      anecdoteElement.appendChild(anecdoteNode);
      CreateLabel.appendChild(anecdoteElement);

    } else {
      CreateLabel.style.backgroundColor = "red";  // On set le style a green quand c'est juste
      answerElement.disabled = true;

    }
  })
```

Hi, here is my problem, I want to click disable the 3 other inputs, here my input is answerElement, except what I did disable the input on click, but I want to disable the other 4 on click and I can't find it

```
 for (let i = 0; i < value.length - 10; i++) {
var score = 0;
const QuestElement = document.createElement("h2"); // Ici on crée toute les question en fonction la taille de value, ici 30 - 10 (-10 pour pas que ce soit les mêmes questions)
const QuestNode = document.createTextNode(value[i].question); // Ici on crée un textnode pour mettre les questions dans h2
QuestElement.appendChild(QuestNode); // Ici on le fait spawn

answersDiv.appendChild(QuestElement);

for (let j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
  // Ici c'est pour crée les Propositions pour chaque questions
  const answerElement = document.createElement("input"); // On crée un input
  answerElement.id = "salut" + j;
  answerElement.value = j;
  answerElement.type = "radio"; // le Type = radio
  answerElement.name = "input";
  answerElement.classList = "input";

  const CreateLabel = document.createElement("label"); // On crée le label pour les inputs
  CreateLabel.classList = "Label";
  CreateLabel.name = "input";

  CreateLabel.setAttribute("for", "salut" + j); // Ici on le setUnAttribut
  const answerNode = document.createTextNode(value[i].propositions[j]); // On crée le TextNode
```

Comment: The behavior makes no sense unless you want to remove the click handling of the inputs as well. I have an updated solution but I need to know if you'd want that as well. Also, if you have radio buttons with the same name then only one can be checked. If you have 12 answers for 3 questions then there would be only one checked button no matter what.

Comment: Hey in fact I generate the proposals with a loop which takes the values of my json file so for each question I generate 4 proposals, then I start again for the next question, but suddenly all the proposals have the same name: salut0, salut1 , salut2, salut3

Comment: Ok it looks like the behaior works correctly with radio buttons. I assume you wanted the user to click an answer but not be able to change it. I added a function that will give every set of 4 radios a unique name to share.

Comment: Ho okey thx! so i have to change all my code, because i generate answers with a for, i will add the code in my first questions

Comment: The answer is really generic, just remove the event handling stuff from OP code and have the code in my answer at the bottom of the script.

Comment: Hoo yeah, i change my Element.name , by your loop, and that's work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, if my answer resolved the issue, go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Done, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `<form>` around all of the `<input>`s. Add the event listener to the `<form>` and have the event handler delegate the click event for the `<input>`s. Wrap each set of 4 `<input>`s in a `<fieldset>` and reference them from the clicked `<input>`. Also a function `nameRadios()` has been added so that each set of 4 radios will share a unique name. See [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Reference the <form>
const form = document.forms[0];
// Pass the event object
const switchInput = event => {
  // This is the <form>
  const listener = event.currentTarget;
  // This is the element the user clicked
  const clicked = event.target;
  /*
  if the element the user clicked was
  an <input>...
  */
  if (clicked.matches('input')) {
    // ...reference the <fieldset> clicked is in...
    let fSet = clicked.parentElement;
    // ...collect all of the <input>s in an array...
    let answers = [...fSet.querySelectorAll('input')];
    //...disable all <input>...
    answers.forEach(input => input.disabled = true);
    //...then enable clicked
    clicked.disabled = false;
  }
};
/*
Have the <form> listen for any clicks
*/
form.onclick = switchInput;

const nameRadios = () => {
  // Collect all radios into an array
  const allRadios = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[type='radio']`)];
  // Each set of 4 radios get a unique name
  for (let i = 0; i < allRadios.length; i++) {
    let q = Math.floor(i / 4);
    allRadios[i].name = `rad${q}`;
  }
};

nameRadios();
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
    <input type='radio'><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is to select all other radio input beside `answerElement` and disable them all:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`[name=${answerElement.name}]`).forEach(
  (otherAnswer)=> {
    otherAnswer.disabled = true;
  }
);
```